# Python/OpenCV : Laser curve analysis from camera video flow

Tags: python, opencv

Good morning,

I'm currently trying to study real-time liquid surface deformations by sending a laser sheet on the surface and gathering its reflection. What I obtain is typically a bright curve at each timestep, and I wish to analyze its coordinates.

I thus brought myself to write a Python script, which is displayed right below (The analysis part is retaken from [laser curved line detection using opencv and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561893/laser-curved-line-detection-using-opencv-and-python), as it represents nearly exactly what I'm trying to do, except that I'm working with a video flow) :

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import cv2.cv as cv
import numpy as np
import time

myfile = open("hauteur.txt","w")

#Import camera flow

class Target:

   def __init__(self):
      self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
      cv.namedWindow("Target", 1)
      cv.SetCaptureProperty(self.capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 150)
      cv.SetCaptureProperty(self.capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 980)
      cv.SetCaptureProperty(self.capture,cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 60 )

   def run(self):
      frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
      frame_size = cv.GetSize(frame)
      color_image_cv = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 3)
      color_image = np.array(color_image_cv)
      grey_image = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
      first = True
      t = time.clock()

      # Frame analysis

      while True:

           ret, bw = cv2.threshold(color_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
           contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)                        
           curves = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), np.uint8) 

           for i in range(len(contours)):
                for col in range(draw.shape[1]):
                     M = cv2.moments(draw[:, col])
                     if M['m00'] != 0:
                          x = col
                          y = int (M['m01']/M['m00'])
                          curves[y, x, :] = (0, 0, 255)
                     res = {'X' : x, 'Y' : y, 't' : t}
                     print res
                     myfile.write('{X}\t{Y}\t{t}'.format(**res))
                     myfile.write("\n")

           cv2.ShowImage("Target", color_image)
           # Listen for ESC key
           c = cv2.WaitKey(7) % 0x100
           if c == 27:
                   break   


if __name__=="__main__":
   t = Target()
   t.run()
```

However, the use of cv and cv2 functions within the same code seems to bring a nice mess and I get the error

```
src data type = 17 is not supported
```

from line

```
ret, bw = cv2.threshold(color_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
```

I understand this arises from the way cv and cv2 functions create and store images, but any conversion process I try doesn't seem to work, and I didn't find equivalent cv2 functions to insert in my video flow importing part (but, as you may understand, I'm clearly not a programming pro and I may have skipped what I'd need in the documentation). Is there then a way to conciliate these cv and cv2 functions, or get a equivalent camera flow with cv2 functions ?

Bonus question : How fast can an script like this run (considering that I'd eventually need this to run at 300-400 fps, I'm not even sure this is actually feasible) ?

Thanks for your attention

Comment: could you try to stick to the cv2 interface ? cv2.cv is deprecated, and won't be available in upcoming opencv3.0. cv2 is using numpy arrays for images, so you should stick with that.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do, with no success as for now... But I will seek for a more efficient way to import my camera flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, cv2 video code:

```
   def __init__(self):
      self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
      cv2.namedWindow("Target", 1)
      self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 150)
      self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 980)
      self.capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS, 60 )

   def run(self):
      ok, frame = self.capture.read()
      gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
      ...
```

Bonus question : ofc, it can only run as fast, as the capture delivers. 300fps seems absurd, 30fps, more likely.

Comment: Aaaaand.. now I'm truly ashamed it is that easy and I completely missed these functions in the doc. My deepest thanks !